# How do I convert nil to 0 in an array to get the sum?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sum, conways-game-of-life

Working on a version of Conway's Game of Life using 2d arrays and when trying too calculate the sum of each cell's "neighbors", I keeping getting blocked by the nil values.

```
  def neighbor_count
      grid.each_with_index do |row, idx|
          row.each_with_index do |column, idx2|
              [grid[idx - 1][idx2 - 1], grid[idx - 1][idx2], grid[idx - 1][idx2 + 1],
              grid[idx][idx2 - 1], grid[idx][idx2], grid[idx][idx2 + 1],
              grid[idx + 1][idx2 - 1], grid[idx + 1][idx2], grid[idx + 1][idx2 + 1]
              ].compact.sum

          end
      end
  end
```

.compact seems to yield the most results if include "puts" in front of the array but none of the options I've tried give me 100%. I've tried reduce(:+), inject, .to_i, reject (to get rid of the nil values), and so forth.

What's missing here?

Error: world.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in neighbor_count': undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Line 35 is the line above ].compact.sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nil values are only a symptom of the illness. Don't treat the symptoms, get rid of the problem! Which is that you are violating array bounds.

`.each_with_index` enumerates all indexes from the first to the last. And so `idx + 1` on the last index will trigger this out-of-bounds situation. And `idx - 1` on the first will produce an unexpected value instead of an error, which will impact your calculations. Good luck debugging that. :)

Put some guard checks in your code, to make sure you never go out of bounds.

---

Just to be absolutely clear, the problem is not that `grid[idx + 1][idx2]` is nil and messes up your calculations. It is that `grid[idx + 1]` **is nil**! And, naturally, you can't do `nil[idx2]`. That's the error.

Comment: Thanks. I get that, and expected to generate nil values because it. Any suggestions on how to efficiently exclude any coordinates that are out of bounds?

Comment: @JeremyFlanagan: yep, some if's will do the job just fine.

Comment: @JeremyFlanagan: here's a game of life I coded _years_ ago. So no judging on the code https://gist.github.com/stulentsev/0e25ae7b079466412a87de26fc4f11be :)

Comment: Thanks! I think I've seen this one, or at least very similar. I'm trying to create mine without multiple classes, at least for this version. Still very new to ruby, so forgive stupid errors. Your suggestion worked, and now I'm working through creating the next generation.

Comment: You can avoid the bounds checking by using a hash instead of an array. `grid[1][2]` would become `grid[[1, 2]]`. You can even give the hash a default value of `0`.

Comment: @Stefan: or encapsulate cell access in a method (which will contain appropriate guards and defaults): `get_cell(1, 2)`

Comment: Breaking the code into smaller chunks is always a good idea. It also makes it easier to test. You do write tests @JeremyFlanagan, don't you? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Declare your grid with 1 layer of border then there wont be any need to put extra if/else clause, Also use direction vectors to access neighbours in loop.

```
#let say you want to delare 4x4 grid, declare grid of (row+2, col+2)
row, col, default_value = 4, 4, 0
grid = Array.new(row+2){Array.new(col+2,default_value)}

# store direction vectors dx and dy
dx = [-1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
dy = [-1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0]
(1..row).each do |i|
  (1..col).each do |j|
      puts (0..8).reduce(0) { |sum, k| sum + grid[i + dx[k]][j + dy[k]]}
end
```

Comment: If one were to use padding, it must be added on _all_ sides of the field, no?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks sir for pointing this out, good catch, edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the enumeration of the neighbors into a separate method:

```
def each_neighbor(x, y)
  raise IndexError unless within_bounds?(x, y)
  return enum_for(:each_neighbor, x, y) unless block_given?
  (y - 1).upto(y + 1) do |j|
    (x - 1).upto(x + 1) do |i|
      next unless within_bounds?(i, j)  # skip out of bounds cells
      next if i == x && j == y          # skip middle cell
      yield grid[i][j]
    end
  end
end
```

Given coordinates `x` and `y` this code  will simply yield the (valid) neighbors. The first line returns an enumerator if no block is given.

Instead of the nested [`upto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Integer.html#method-i-upto) loops, you could also utilize [`repeated_permutation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation) to generate offsets:

```
[-1, 0, 1].repeated_permutation(2) do |dx, dy|
  next unless within_bounds?(x + dx, y + dy)
  next if dx.zero? && dy.zero? # skip middle cell
  yield grid[x + dx][y + dy]
end
```

More important however is that returning an enumerator allows you to chain methods from [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html) like:

```
def grid
  [[1, 2, 1],
   [2, 3, 2],
   [1, 2, 1]]
end

each_neighbor(1, 1).sum    #=> 12
each_neighbor(1, 1).count  #=> 8

each_neighbor(0, 0).sum    #=> 7
each_neighbor(0, 0).count  #=> 3
```